# How can I get doxygen to document a template class defined in .tcc file?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, doxygen

I have used `Code::Blocks` to create a `C++` project. I have three project files: A `.hxx` file which contains the declaration of a class template; a `.tcc` file in which the member functions of the class template are defined and documented; and a `.cxx` file which contains a program that tests an instance of the class. I have used the `doxygen` interface in `Code::Blocks` to document all the files. However, when I use the `doxygen` interface generate the documentation for the project, the `doxygen`-generated documentation does not include both the implementation code and the documentation in the `.tcc` file.

Does somebody know what I should do to have `doxygen` generate the documentation in the `.tcc` file? Any help with regard to the solution of this problem would be appreciated highly.

Answer (score 3):

From a standard Doxyfile

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# The INPUT tag is used to specify the files and/or directories that contain
# documented source files. You may enter file names like myfile.cpp or
# directories like /usr/src/myproject. Separate the files or directories with
# spaces. See also FILE_PATTERNS and EXTENSION_MAPPING
# Note: If this tag is empty the current directory is searched.

INPUT = path/to/src/dir

# If the value of the INPUT tag contains directories, you can use the
# FILE_PATTERNS tag to specify one or more wildcard patterns (like *.cpp and
# *.h) to filter out the source-files in the directories.
#
# Note that for custom extensions or not directly supported extensions you also
# need to set EXTENSION_MAPPING for the extension otherwise the files are not
# read by doxygen.
#
# If left blank the following patterns are tested:*.c, *.cc, *.cxx, *.cpp,
# *.c++, *.java, *.ii, *.ixx, *.ipp, *.i++, *.inl, *.idl, *.ddl, *.odl, *.h,
# *.hh, *.hxx, *.hpp, *.h++, *.cs, *.d, *.php, *.php4, *.php5, *.phtml, *.inc,
# *.m, *.markdown, *.md, *.mm, *.dox, *.py, *.pyw, *.f90, *.f, *.for, *.tcl,
# *.vhd, *.vhdl, *.ucf, *.qsf, *.as and *.js.

FILE_PATTERNS          = *.tcc *.cxx *.hxx
```

also see:

[Doxygen input file documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#config_input)

[Doxygen file pattern documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_file_patterns)

Comment: Thank you very much @tike. The solution that you have suggested has worked perfectly for me. Cheers!